# Yii relational search

Tags: php, search, yii

I tried to "do my homework" before asking, but none of the methods I tried seem to work, so I need help. ( I'm not an expert with Yii )

My problem is that I would like a searchbox on my index page which would help me search movies by tags.
I found a [useful article](http://learnyii.blogspot.hu/2011/01/creating-instant-search-box-for.html)
, so basically thats how I started.

I have the following tables:

movie

tag

movie_has_tag ( which has movie_id and tag_id in it )

// and what I think I need for the search are movie_title and tag_name

relation in BaseMovie:

```
public function relations(){
    return array(
        'tags' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Tag', 'movie_has_tag(movie_id, tag_id)'),
    );
}
```

relation in BaseTag:

```
public function relations(){
    return array(
        'movies' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Movie', 'movie_has_tag(tag_id, movie_id)'),
    );
}
```

I tried it this way:

```
public function actionIndex(){
    if( isset($_GET['q']) ){
        $model = new Movie($scenario='search');

        $model->unsetAttributes();

        $tag = $_GET['q'];

        // this is how I tried
        $tags = Movie::model()->with('tags')->findAllByAttributes( array('movie_title' => $tag));

        $this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),  
        ));

}
```

with this code, nothing happens when I start typing into the searchbox.

---

EDIT:
@Stu

I've read the link and came up with the following.
I added this relation to BaseMovie:

```
'tagz' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Tag', array('movie_id'=>'tag_id', 'through'=>'MovieTags')).
```

Then I edited the thing that was in actionIndex:

```
if( isset($_GET['q']) ){
        $model = new Movie($scenario='search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();

        $movies = Movie::model()->withTag($_GET['q'])->findAll();
        $tags = $movies->movieTags;
}
```

The instant searchbox becomes incative when I start typing into it and all movies disappear ( none of them comes back even after I delete what I typed in. I have to refresh the page ).

EDIT v2:
The _view is quite simple:

```
<div class="view">
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->title); ?>
</div>
```

Everything else ( like the index page ) is the same as in the link which I mentioned the first time.

Comment: do $movies and $tags contain anything at all here: `$movies = Movie::model()->withTag($_GET['q'])->findAll();
        $tags = $movies->movieTags;`

Comment: I think the tagz relation should read: `'tagz' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Tag', array('movie_id'=>'tag_id'), 'through'=>'MovieTags')` and you defined the MovieTags relation too?

Comment: sure, movieTags is defined just like you mentioned in your post.
I'm not sure how to test $movies and $tags as the instant search thing does not let me var_dump them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've read what you wrote here (both question and first answer) and will try solve your problem BEFORE your "EDIT: @Stu" mark, cause after that you've started doing something strange that i didn't get to understand.

You have 2 models `Movie` and `Tag`.
The relations in `Movie` model are like you've written before:

```
public function relations(){
  return array(
    'tags' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Tag', 'movie_has_tag(movie_id, tag_id)'),
  );
}
```

The relations in `Tag` model are same as you've written before:

```
public function relations(){
  return array(
    'movies' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Movie', 'movie_has_tag(tag_id, movie_id)'),
  );
}
```

Now you create new method in your `Movie` model:

```
public function searchByTag($q)
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->with = 'tags';
    $criteria->together = true;
    $criteria->compare('`tags`.`name`', $q, true, 'OR');
    // You can add here another comparision to search in your movie title, for example
    // $criteria->compare('`t`.`title`', $q, true, 'OR');
    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

In your controller the action should be something like this:

```
public function actionIndex() {
    if( isset($_GET['q']) ) {
        $tag = $_GET['q']; // Please add needed safety measures, for example with HTMLPurifier
        $this->render('index', array(
            'dataProvider'=>Movie::model()->searchByTag($tag),  
        ));
    } else
        $this->render('index');
}
```

Hopefully this is useful.

Comment: It works like a charm man! thank you very much for your help :)
If you have a little more time to me, you made me curious with this "another comparison thing". When I uncomment the title-search lines, it does not work, and till I dont delete it the tag search does not work either :/

Comment: @TibiB I updated the code of search method. I added 'OR' to each compare. Try it now.